cudaMalloc and cudaMemCpy errors when using multiple threads with OpenMP and CUDA
I am trying to run multiple different tasks on multiple CPU threads in parallel while utilizing CUDA in each thread.  Using the starting project for CUDA Visual Studio 2022 the project runs with no problems without openMP. Also, openMP is working correctly and is running on multiple threads.
The problem is coming from trying to use both at the same time.  Some threads work flawlessly while other threads return errors for cudaMalloc and/or cudaMemcpy, but only sporadically on random threads.  Of the 24 threads I have running, a variable amount of them will work correctly while others throw the errors. It is different every time I run the program with which threads run correctly and which ones don't from 3-4 threads working to 20 or so threads with no errors.
Here is my source code
test.cpp file:
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "heads.h"
int main()
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        test();
        printf("Hello World... from thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }
    return 0;
}

heads.h file:
#pragma once
int test();

tester.cu file:
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "heads.h"

cudaError_t addWithCuda(int* c, const int* a, const int* b, unsigned int size);

__global__ void addKernel(int* c, const int* a, const int* b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] * b[i];
}

int test()
{
    const int arraySize = 5;
    const int a[arraySize] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const int b[arraySize] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    int c[arraySize] = { 0 };

    // Add vectors in parallel.
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda(c, a, b, arraySize);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }


        printf("{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {%d,%d,%d,%d,%d}\n",
            c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]);
    

    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
cudaError_t addWithCuda(int* c, const int* a, const int* b, unsigned int size)
{
    int* dev_a = 0;
    int* dev_b = 0;
    int* dev_c = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Allocate GPU buffers for three vectors (two input, one output)    .
    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!c\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!a\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size * sizeof(int));
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMalloc failed!b\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Copy input vectors from host memory to GPU buffers.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!a\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!b\n");
        goto Error;
    }

    // Launch a kernel on the GPU with one thread for each element.
    addKernel << <1, size >> > (dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);

    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }
    
    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }
    
    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaStatus = cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, size * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaMemcpy failed!c\n");
        goto Error;
    }

Error:
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);

    return cudaStatus;
}

Sample Result:
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
Hello World... from thread = 3
Hello World... from thread = 4
cudaMemcpy failed!a
Hello World... from thread = 18
cudaMalloc failed!b
Hello World... from thread = 9
Hello World... from thread = 0
cudaMemcpy failed!a
Hello World... from thread = 16
cudaMalloc failed!b
Hello World... from thread = 13
cudaMemcpy failed!a
Hello World... from thread = 10
cudaMalloc failed!b
cudaMemcpy failed!a
cudaMalloc failed!b
cudaMalloc failed!b
cudaMemcpy failed!a
cudaMalloc failed!b
cudaMalloc failed!b
addWithCuda failed!
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
addWithCuda failed!
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
addWithCuda failed!
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
addWithCuda failed!
{1,2,3,4,5} + {10,20,30,40,50} = {10,40,90,160,250}
addWithCuda failed!
Hello World... from thread = 17
addWithCuda failed!
Hello World... from thread = 11
addWithCuda failed!
Hello World... from thread = 7
addWithCuda failed!
Hello World... from thread = 8
addWithCuda failed!
Hello World... from thread = 14
addWithCuda failed!
Hello World... from thread = 21
addWithCuda failed!
Hello World... from thread = 1
addWithCuda failed!
Hello World... from thread = 2
Hello World... from thread = 22
Hello World... from thread = 6
Hello World... from thread = 15
Hello World... from thread = 12
Hello World... from thread = 20
Hello World... from thread = 19
Hello World... from thread = 5
Hello World... from thread = 23

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

You are executing cudaDeviceReset() in test, which is parallelized. So you reset the device while some threads may still use it.

@Homer512 Thanks, its working now.  As soon as I read your answer I was lie "Of course, I'm a dummy"

Alright. I assume you are aware that cudaDeviceSynchronize is a bad fit, too, as is cudaMemcpy, or async memcpy without pinned host memory. And you likely want a stream per thread. Otherwise your CPU threads will needlessly synchronize with each other instead of running independently

--default-stream per-thread might be of interest.
